# using EJS with requirejs

Tags: requirejs, ejs

I had a problem include ejs into requirejs. I put `<script data-main="js/app" src="js/require.js"></script>` in my  and inside of body create EJS object.

In my app.js,

```
require.config({

paths: {
    //library
    jquery: 'lib/jquery-1.11.1.min',
    jquerymobile: "lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min", 
    text: 'text',
    ejs: 'ejs_0.9_alpha_1_production'
},
shim: {
    "ejs": {
        exports: 'ejs'
      }
}
});

require(['jquery', 'jquerymobile','text','ejs'], function ($, mobile) {
    console.log('jQuery version:', $.fn.jquery); // 1.9.0
});
```

when it is running, it throws EJS is not defined error. However, if I include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ejs_0.9_alpha_1_production.js"></script>
```

in the head, everything goes well.

Regards
Hammer

Comment: I also found requirejs hard to use with other libraries and vice-versa. That is why I created a library which is much easier to use and is tested with angular. There is a demo application at the bottom: http://gngeorgiev.github.io/Modulerr.js/

Answer (score 1):

Lately I just get through similar trouble using ejs from the browser. I post the answer as it could save somebody's time.

I suggest you double check your ejs library is indeed coming from https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs. There is quite some tuned version of ejs around right now because it is becoming very popular. Unfortunatly most of thoses versions target specific needs and return different object to the window (eg. EJS instead of ejs) or don't even return anything usefull for requirejs.

=> In both case this would expalin why your shim exports return `undefined`.

Once you get it to load properly, let me also spot on an awesome requirejs-ejs plugin at https://github.com/whitcomb/requirejs-ejs . It could help you preload and render your template in a nice requirejs way.